# Sci-fi horror comic book about a man who's brain was placed inside of a robot body to save him

Tags: story-identification, comics

I read this old sci-fi horror comic at least 25-35 years ago - not being able to remember the title has been driving me crazy for months.

Here's what I remember of the story:

A man's brain has been placed inside a robot body (perhaps to save him from an incurable disease). Because he can't stand to be reminded of what he was, he travels to a world populated by sentient robots where all organic life is illegal. The only thing that stops the robots from destroying him is that his human tissue is hidden inside his metal body.

He discovers that his brain is slowly dying and he needs a large transfusion of human blood to stay alive. He travels to see the woman he loved before he was made into a cyborg and she offers her blood to save his life, though it will cost her own. He accepts her offer, becoming in effect a cyborg vampire.

When he arrives back on the sentient robot world, the robots detect the blood in glass containers he unthinkingly left strapped to his chest and blast the containers, destroying the blood and condemning him to a slow painful death.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it - story "Union in Steel", comic [*Time Warp*](http://babblingsaboutdccomics.blogspot.com/2017/12/time-warp-5-time-warp-ends-with-eight.html), issue 5, by DC comics, published March 1980, meaning I saw it when I was around 12 (I'm now 50).

The below page shows the cyborg, woman and the blood vials strapped to the cuborg's chest:

[image: Time Warp comic page]